# Datatable gets reset unexpectedly

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datatable, infragistics

I have a datagrid which refreshes every 3 seconds and while refresh happens Datatable gets reset everytime unexpectedly. What i do is adding values from one datatable to another.

However if use 'DefaultView.ToTable' it stores the data.

Basically, I have 2 datatables dtTopSQL and dtCurTopSQL.

dtTopSQL getting new data and adding to the datatable dtCurTopSQL and I want to store the rows in dtCurTopSQL;

```
  // Initial Load the Datatable Structure
  private void Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dtTopSQL.Columns.Add("SQL_ID", typeof(string));
        dtTopSQL.Columns.Add("Count", typeof(Int16));
        dtTopSQL.Columns.Add("CurTime", typeof(DateTime));
    }

 // Timer start refreshing the datagrid
 private void timer_TimerTopSQL(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dtTopSQL.Clear(); // Clear before the Fill
        odaTopSQL = new OracleDataAdapter(getTopSQLString, oradb);
        odaTopSQL.Fill(dtTopSQL);
        getTopSQL();
    }

// Merging datatable starts here.
public void getTopSQL()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dtTopSQL.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            bool isDupe = false;
            for (j = 0; j < dtCurTopSQL.Rows.Count; j++)
            {
                if (dtTopSQL.Rows[i][0].ToString() == dtCurTopSQL.Rows[j][0].ToString())
                {

                    dtCurTopSQL.Rows[j][1] = int.Parse(dtCurTopSQL.Rows[j][1].ToString()) + int.Parse(dtTopSQL.Rows[i][1].ToString());
                    dtCurTopSQL.Rows[j][2] = CurDate;
                    isDupe = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!isDupe)
            {
                dtCurTopSQL.ImportRow(dtTopSQL.Rows[i]);
                dtCurTopSQL.Rows[j][2] = CurDate;
            }
        }

        ugTopSQL.DataSource = dtCurTopSQL; // Bind the merged Datatable.
    }
```

Above code works if i use below before just binding data;

```
dtCurTopSQL = dtCurTopSQL.DefaultView.ToTable();
```

However i don't understand why? I want to store data without using DefaultView.ToTable

Could you explain please?

Answer (score 1):

> Above code works if i use below before just binding data;

`dtCurTopSQL = dtCurTopSQL.DefaultView.ToTable();`

> However i don't understand why? I want to store data without using
>   DefaultView.ToTable

`ugTopSQL.DataSource = dtCurTopSQL; // Bind the merged Datatable.`

The first time this statement is executed, the DataSource changes from null to dtCurTopSQL.  Each subsequent time it is executed, the DataSource setter checks if the new value is the same as its existing value and if so it does nothing.

By assigning a new table to dtCurTopSQL before assigning the DataSource you are assigning a new object to the DataSource, so it acts according with the new source.

A simple solution would be to add

`ugTopSQL.DataSource = null;`

as the first statement in the getTopSQL method.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is absolutely unnecessary. When UltraGrid is bound to DataTable each time data table's rows change the grid will automatically show this change. So change your Load event like this:

```
// Initial Load the Datatable Structure
  private void Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dtTopSQL.Columns.Add("SQL_ID", typeof(string));
        dtTopSQL.Columns.Add("Count", typeof(Int16));
        dtTopSQL.Columns.Add("CurTime", typeof(DateTime));
        ugTopSQL.DataSource = dtCurTopSQL; // Bind the merged Datatable.
    }
```

Then remove this row from getTopSQL method:

```
ugTopSQL.DataSource = dtCurTopSQL; // Bind the merged Datatable.
```

This way whatever changes you made to dtCurTopSQL will be automatically shown in the grid without setting the grid's DataSource, which by the way is expensive operation and should not be done each three seconds.

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer. however it returns nothing.

Comment: What returns nothing?

Answer (score 0):

Best solution is use DataTable.Select(_filter) method instead of dataview/datatable.defaultview etc... if you want to stop datagridview reset automatically.